# Map entity for embeddable class

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have written a Team entity and a Player entity.

One team has two players.

How can I do the mapping in Hibernate.

By making "Player" an Embeddable entity class and Embedding it two times into "Team" class is one way I think to use. Then how the relationship are going to be mapped. OneToOne or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

A `Team` and a `Player` should be treated as 2 different entities, you cannot embed a `Player` inside `Team`.

You can go through the hibernate document when to use embeddable components:

[5.1.5. Embedded objects (aka components)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-component)

> Embeddable objects (or components) are objects whose properties are
>   mapped to the same table as the owning entity's table. Components can,
>   in turn, declare their own properties, components or collections

Logically, a Team can have many Players, so you need one-to-many relationship.

See the document under section [7.2.2.1. Lists](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-indexed) to know how you can do the mapping.

Comment: how can I deal with retrieving. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399709/how-to-retrive-objects-from-one-to-many-using-hql-or-criteria-api

Answer (score 0):

You need a collection of players on your team class and have to map it as one-to-many, in any of the ways described in the hibernate docs (bag, set, list or whatever).

Do not create a Team class with two Player properties!

Also, when creating optional one-to-one relations (without Foreign Key relation in database, so an orphaned reference is possible), it may be useful to use one-to-many collections (with no or one object) instead of one-to-one, for lazy loading.

Comment: do you know how to implement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399709/how-to-retrive-objects-from-one-to-many-using-hql-or-criteria-api