# How to retrive objects from one to many using HQL or Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria-api

Started to learn hibernate with examples.
I have written a class "Team" that has one to many relationship with (a Collection of) players.

I need to get all the teams

1. where player name is "X" (X is not the primary key of the Player table)
2. where player "Y" is in

I think I have to get this done by using Criteria API or the HQL. Can someone tell how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thsi will work for `OneToMany` relationship, ie 1 Team can Have many `Players`, and every no `Player` will be mapped to more than 1 `Team`.

```
@Entity
public class Team implements Serializable {
private Set<Player>    players;
}


@Entity
public class Player implements Serializable {
private String playerName;
}
```

where player name is "X" (X is not the primary key of the Player table)

```
SELECT t from Team t inner join t.players tp WHERE t.id = :id AND   tp.playerName = :name
```